# How to improve the output of this XOR?

Tags: c, encryption

I am just trying to make a simple encryption that is obviously not secure at all. Everything is just fine but I am getting unprintable characters such as new line or nul. It becomes problem when decoding. How to solve this problem in this code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    char text[1024];

    printf("ENTER SOME TEXT \n");
    fgets(text, 1024, stdin);

    for(i=0;i<strlen(text)-1;++i)
    {
        if(text[i]!=32)
            text[i] ^= i;
    }

    printf("encoded text : %s",text);

    getch();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: use function to print each character by itself, maybe in hex. Pass it the message and its length

Comment: Could you maybe clarify what you want to achieve? Do you not want to have unprintable characters in your string?

Comment: Use something similar to rot13 without changing newline or null chars if you want to preserve readability.

Comment: I want that code to just print printable characters lets say specific sets maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are getting unprintable characters, that's a direct consequence of XORing the values.  Contrary to what you think, this does ***not*** become a problem while decoding.  What ***does*** become a problem while decoding, is your `if(text[i]!=32)` check, which is a) useless, and b) corrupts your output stream.  Get rid of this, and you should get a stream which does of course contain unprintable characters, as it is supposed to, and which should decode just fine.  If you continue to have problems, make sure to post your code which attempts to decode the stream.

Also, taking into account Jakiša Tomić's comment below, (though not exactly as worded,) you need to loop until `strlen(text)` instead of `strlen(text)-1`, so that the null character terminator will also be encoded into the output stream, so that you know when to stop when decoding.

Comment: You are right, but there is still one thing missing: Loop should go to strlen(text) + 1. Otherwise, decoded string will not be terminated.

Comment: @MikeNakis what if there is newline `nul` character and i tried to read from file?

Comment: The question does not say anything about reading from files, nor about writing into files.  That's totally new.  So, nothing about files could be included as part of an answer to this question.  The issue of "how to write arbitrary (binary) bytes into a file and then read them" could perhaps be the subject of an entirely different question.  My answer is an answer to this question, as stated.

Comment: Well, I may be a jerk, but at least I do know how to program, and I do try to help those who are capable of formulating a proper question.  "So I Got That Goin' For Me, Which is Nice."